# JBoss cluster setup on Windows

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

I am trying to set up a jboss cluster on localhost.

Here is my configuration:

In /standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml

```
<protocol type="TCPPING">
       <property name="initial_hosts">0.0.0.0[7600],0.0.0.0[7600]</property>
       <property name="num_initial_members">2</property>
       <property name="port_range">0</property>
       <property name="timeout">2000</property>
</protocol>
```

In the ../mod_cluster-1.3.1.Final-src-ssl/confhttpd.conf, uncommented and added localhost:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Executed:

```
../mod_cluster-1.3.1.Final-src-ssl/bin/installconf.bat
```

Started node1 and node2, and they started successfully.

finally executed: ../mod_cluster-1.3.1.Final-src-ssl/bin/httpd.exe

I see the following exception:

```
14:19:21,877 ERROR [org.jboss.modcluster] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) MODCLUSTER000043: Failed to send INFO to javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/127.0.0.1:6666: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.mcmp.impl.DefaultMCMPHandler$Proxy.getConnection(DefaultMCMPHandler.java:818)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.mcmp.impl.DefaultMCMPHandler$Proxy.getConnectionWriter(DefaultMCMPHandler.java:841)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.mcmp.impl.DefaultMCMPHandler.sendRequest(DefaultMCMPHandler.java:482)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.mcmp.impl.DefaultMCMPHandler.sendRequest(DefaultMCMPHandler.java:583)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.mcmp.impl.DefaultMCMPHandler.status(DefaultMCMPHandler.java:370)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.mcmp.impl.DefaultMCMPHandler.status(DefaultMCMPHandler.java:350)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.ModClusterService.status(ModClusterService.java:458)
        at org.jboss.modcluster.container.catalina.CatalinaEventHandlerAdapter.lifecycleEvent(CatalinaEventHandlerAdapter.java:249)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1323) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1588) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1574) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
```

Any ideas on how to sort this?

Comment: Check anti-virus and firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply says that your JBoss Application Server's mod_cluster subsystem cannot contact mod_cluster balancer in your Apache HTTP Server.

- What does Apache HTTP Server advertises as its location? You can check that with our [Advertize](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/modcluster/mod_proxy_cluster/master/test/java/Advertize.java) utility, no dependencies, just compile with `javac Advertize.java` and run it.
- Is it really listening with a VirtualHost with [EnableMCPMReceive](http://modcluster.io/documentation/#enablemcpmreceive) set on this location: `javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/127.0.0.1:6666`? Like, does the translation of `javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com` to `127.0.0.1` really make sense? It would mean your worker and your balancer are both on the same host - localhost...
- If your Apache HTTP Server keeps getting confused about what it should advertise to your JBoss workers, tune the [ServerAdvertise](http://modcluster.io/documentation/#serveradvertise) directive in your mod_cluster.conf, e.g. if the `javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com`'s IP address accessible from all your JBoss worker nodes is 172.172.120.16 and the VrtualHost is available on port 6666, then set it to: `ServerAdvertise On http://172.172.120.16:6666`. If you prefer using hostnames, it is also valid to stick to `ServerAdvertise On http://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com:6666` but then your worker nodes must be able to translate that to 172.172.120.16 not 127.0.0.1.
- Do not bind your worker nodes to 0.0.0.0.  Each worker node's http/https/ajp (whichever you use, AJP is default for mod_cluster) socker binding must be accessible to the balancer so as it could send requests to it. Furthermore, worker nodes must be able to **report their IP addresses or hostnames to the balancer so as it knows where to contanct them**. E.g. each worker must be bound to something like `worker1.intranet.example.org` or `172.172.120.51` so as  it could report to the balancer: *"Hey, I'm worker1, send me requests here: ajp://172.172.120.51:8009/"*
- It won't do if you bind all your workers to 0.0.0.0 and they then report all the same invalid address like ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/ to the balancer that resides on a completely different computer.

Check out http://modcluster.io/

Cheers